# Правильно ли ставить тире после слов «И далее»?

Tags: пунктуация

Автор закончил комментировать выдержку из текста, и переходит к следующей, которая принадлежит Тибетцу. Он это делает таким образом:

> И далее – читаем Тибетца: «...»

Интонационно «И далее» звучит как вводное слово.

Правильно ли поставлено тире? Может нужна запятая, или не нужно ничего?

Comment: Если значение "после этого", то не вводное.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку это вводное слово, то после него нужна запятая. Правило [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вводное, если можно изъять.